# Cumulocity HTML widget cannot access child device data

Tags: cumulocity

I am trying to use HTML widget to display device and child devices property. I created a group and created 3-4 child devices under it. When I am using `{{device.name}}` it is showing the data of the group properly since I chose it as parent asset. But when I am trying to use `{{device[12345].name}}` it is not shoiwng anything.

Answer (score 0):

did a rookie mistake , it will be {{devices[12345].name}}